# Django: external access

Tags: django

I have been setting up a Django website using the development server, and it works fine if I access it using the following address in my browser:

`localhost:8000`

I now want to be able to access the website from another computer (on the same network). I still want to use the development server for now. If my computer's name on the network is `myname`, and the domain is `mydomain.com`, then how can I enable this? If I just type in:

```
myname.mydomain.com:8000
```

I get a `Server not found` error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to access your computer like they way you explained in a LAN. There are couple of ways you can let other computers use your dev server directly.

First, run your Django app like this -

```
$ ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

So that the server listens to all the network interfaces for anyone accessing your IP, not just localhost. Then -

1. Find out your IP in the network. In the other computer in the same network open the `hosts` file(In linux, it's at `/etc/hosts`) and enter a new line -

   ```
   enter.your.ip.here intended.domainname.com
   ```

   Then you can access your dev server from that computer by entering `intended.domainname.com:8000` or `enter.your.ip.here:8000` in the browser. Cons: You have to alter the `hosts` file in each of the computer you intend to use the domain name instead of IP from and they all have to be in the same network.
2. You could use [`localtunnel`](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/). Then you can just execute -

   ```
   $ localtunnel 8000
   ```

   And it'll give you an url like `http://xyz.localtunnel.com` which you can share to anybody using the Internet and they'll be able to use your dev server.

Comment: Additionally, the default runserver only listens on localhost, so to get to it from another computer you'd have to specify 0.0.0.0:8000 after the runserver command.

Comment: Right. Forgot to mention that. Thanks